# Bash: Permission denied when trying to open a file

Tags: linux, bash

I recently decided to try to learn some bash scripting and as a fun exercise I decided to make a script to open up a daily file for me to write notes in whenever the script is run.

It worked fine until I logged out and back in to the system later, when I received an error

`/usr/local/bin/notes: line 45: /home/MY_USERNAME/notes/2010-10-01:Permission denied`

[Code](http://pastebin.com/5XwLtaqE)

I might be mistaken, but this certainly doesn't seem like something that shouldn't require extra permissions, does it?

Editor is set to `nano`

File's permissions are `-rw-rw-r--`

Script's permissions are `-rwxr-xr-x`

Comment: What is your $EDITOR set to?  What are the permissions on the file like?  Also, it's better to include the code in the question itself (in a code block) so that the question archives better, and doesn't become meaningless once the pastebin goes away.

Comment: **everything** requires permissions.  There are no "extra" permissions.  You have to do an `ls -l` or `ls -ld` to see what permissions the files have.

Comment: You should update to include the code for completeness of the question.  The pastbin id is no longer valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that in

```
$EDITOR $DAILY_FILENAME
```

`$EDITOR` is null, so it's trying to execute `$DAILY_FILENAME` which not executable. Probably while you were testing you set EDITOR manually, but didn't add it to your .bashrc (or whatever) file.

Use the `-x` option to prove it.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I didn't permanently set the editor variable, I only had it set for that session. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

check the permission on the file with

```
ls -l /path/to/your/file
```

you should see something like

```
-rw-r--r--
```

r mean readable, w writeable, and x executable.

the first set is for your user, the second set of three is for your group, and the third set is for anyone.

so in my example, the file i have shown is read/write for me, and read only for my group and for any other user.

Use the chmod command to change permissions.

```
chmod 744 file
```

will make the file read/write/exec for you, and just read for user/world.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I would suggest that the `$EDITOR` environment variable is undefined for some reason. It looks like your script is attempting to execute the notes file - as this isn't executable you get the unhelpful error message.